# Is there a default confidentiality url I can link to?

Tags: mac-appstore, app-store-connect

I am updating my app on the App Store and I now have to give a url for confidentiality agreement.

Is there a default one I can link to, e.g a basic one that Apple would provide for small developers? Or do I have to write one from scratch and host it on my website?

Comment: There seem to be two question hidden here: a) is there a template I can use/which text should I use, and b) where to host it. A) goes into legal advice territory which is off-topic here

Comment: Would be just really nice from Apple to have a few templates we could link to. (and if there was one it would not be off topic).

Comment: Especially due to all the legal details involved it probably would be rather risky for Apple to provide templates. Because if those templates fail to cover a specific situation you could sue them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll want to host your metadata sites to avoid rejection in the review process. Something as simple as a GitHub static page should suffice if the content you post is correct and appropriate. Focus on getting the requirements satisfied and the hosting will sort itself out much easier.